# SATA cables: is there a distinction between SATA1, SATA2, etc.?

Tags: hard-drive, ssd, sata

I just installed a SSD with a SATA3 interface on my SATA2-only motherboard. Since I was out of cables, I had to use a leftover SATA cable from an older SATA1-only mobo (so I assume that it's a SATA-1 only cable, if such a distinction exists). Now, my searches here seem to indicate that things should work without problems, but I'm concerned about whether using an older cable will lead to decreased performance. I'm okay with the SSD topping at 3Gb./s (SATA2 speed), but will the cable make the drive go slower than that?

Answer (score 3):

Cables can't negotiate. The drive and controller will still negotiate the highest version they both support.